# Core data memory leaks from _PFAllocateObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks

While running the leaks instruments, the one place where there is a memory leak is within core data. The responsible frame as indicated by the trace is within the _PFAllocateObjects. This looks like an internal mechanism, and I do wonder if this is related to faulting the managedObjects and is not a real leak. If you want to see a bigger image, simply click on the image to have it expand. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not a real leak and the size even if they were, are of no consequence.

You can safely ignore them.